# Setup credit card

Tags: orders, paypal, paypal-express

How to make setup credit card, why i can't order with credit card. This is notification.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [the paypal error codes](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/) this "occurs when the billing agreement is disabled or inactive." [This page](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/content/payment/paypal-billing-agreements.html) gives good instructions on how to enable it.

Comment: I do like this, [http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/content/payment/paypal-billing-agreements.html]
 but, merchan number still invalid.